# BiquadFilterNode.Q for the NOTCH filter

Tags: html, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I cannot find any documentation on how the [`BiquadFilterNode.Q`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode/Q) value works if you set the [`BiquadFilterNode.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode/type) to be `'notch'`. The notch filter should, in practice, attenuate signals within a range of frequencies, but `BiquadFilterNode.frequency` seems to control "the center of the range of frequencies" and the `Q` value is said to control "the width of the frequency band".

However, there is no info on what units would be used. Say, if I want to attenuate signals with frequencies between 300 Hz - 700 Hz, the center is 500 Hz so I set the `frequency` to be that, but what value of `Q` would be correct for this range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulled this off the internet but try it out:

```
// fc = cutoff frequency
// f2 = upper cutoff frequency
// f1 = lower cutoff frequency 
Q = (f2 - f1) / fc;
```

Wikipedia article on Q factor: [Q Factor Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor)

Electronics Learning website: [Quality Factor Calculator](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Quality-factor-calculator.php)

Comment: It does seem to work, with attenuation restricted to frequencies between f1 and f2. It seems to do it very gradually though, but that's probably something I can figure out myself.

Comment: Not sure why it's happening gradually but good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#filters-characteristics, the formulas for the biquad filters are based on notes at http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

This says the Q and bandwidth are related by the formula

`1/Q = 2*sinh(ln(2)/2*BW*w0/sin(w0))`

where `w0 = = 2*pi*f0/Fs` and `f0` is the center frequency and `Fs` is the sample rate.