# In The Web Audio Api, How to set correctly the Q value of a BiquadFilter for 1/3 of Octave

Tags: web-audio-api

I want to emulate a clasic 1/3 band analog eq and 1 octave eq. I am using BiquadFilter (Peaking) but I am not able to find out how to correctly set up the `Q` value for this.

In the WAA documentation are no examples of equivalences or example values. Does anybody know how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45249984) that points to [The Audio EQ Cookbook](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt) and says:

> As mentioned in https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#filters-characteristics, the formulas for the biquad filters are based on notes at http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt
>
> This says the Q and bandwidth are related by the formula 
>   `1/Q = 2*sinh(ln(2)/2*BW*w0/sin(w0))`
>   where `w0 = = 2*pi*f0/Fs` and `f0` is the center frequency and `Fs` is the sample rate.

In that equation I am not sure how to get correctly the Bandwidth, for example in this page http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-bandwidth.htm we can see a formula that states `BW = f2 − f1` where `f2` is the next frequency on the Eq and `f1` the previous freq?

For example if the EQ is 1/3 Octave, the center frequency is 1Khz and the Sample Rate 44100hz,

> f2 = 1250Hz
>   f0 = 1000Hz
>   f1 = 800hz
>
> w0 = 2*pi*1000 / 44100 = 0.14247585730565954
>
> BW = 1250hz - 800hz = 450

But that gives a Q of `1.09283639196669×10^-68` that is too little. But if I asume the `BW` as 1/3 (like one third of octave) it gives `4.30381250657881` that is almost the same as the BW to Q calculator in the same Sengpiel Audio website.

So Why  `BW = f2 − f1` ? Should I use `BW = 1` for One octave or `BW = 1/3` for One third for in `Q` equation?

Also, is this Q value compatible with `BiquadFilter.Q` values or do I have to normalize it?

Comment: Yeah, the spec is not a tutorial and kind of assumes you already know what you're doing.  Having said that, I also agree that there does need to be more material on this.  I can't figure out the relationship between Q and BW for the peaking filter either.  The formulas give really unexpected values for Q or BW.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627013/how-do-i-configure-a-bandpass-filter/15629476#15629476

Comment: @KevinEnnis yes it was helpul! Your formula is the best direct way to get the Q I need for the biquadFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Peaking Equalizers](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Peaking_Equalizers.html) gives a nice description and a simple relationship between Q and the BW.  Combining this with the audio cookbook should give you the information you need to create the desired peaking filters.

Comment: That was dense I did not saw anything like that since my days learning audio tech! Thanks Raymond but I have to give this one to [Kevin Ennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717965/kevin-ennis) mostly because that formula is easier to implement.

Comment: But a peaking filter is not a bandpass filter.  But whatever.

Comment: your are right... it does not take in consideration the gain. Sorry.

Comment: It's on my list of things to to do:  Create some kind of tutorial or something that tells how to go from an analog filter to the equivalent webaudio biquad filter.  Someday.